# Is there a way to check if any files are open before unmounting the file system?

Tags: filesystems, aix

In AIX,

is there any command or way to verify, before unmounting a file system, is there any open files from that file system?

Or any method to verify if the filesystem is busy before attempting an unmount operation in AIX?

I verified fuser and lsof commands. lsof is not a native command and fuser does not report all  open files on the file system.

Comment: How about this: `if ! MSG=$(umount / 2>&1); then printf 'umount error %s\n' "$MSG"; else printf 'No problem here'; fi`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about this "fuser does not report all open files"?
According to the man page, it should:
"The fuser command lists the process numbers of local processes that use
the local or remote files specified by the File parameter. For block
special devices, the command lists the processes that use any file on
that device."